# PHP FastCGI not starting [Apache]

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I've set up a few websites on my localhost using PHP7 on Apache.

Whenever I start my Apache server, my Windows Event Viewer logs an error saying my php-cgi.exe is faulty.
The websites I'm trying to view give a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Here is the full error:

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 7.0.5.0, time stamp: 0x56fc0ab8
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.18362.719, time stamp: 0x832e7bce
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00088d30
Faulting process id: 0x31f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5f77b2a6b3a9d
Faulting application path: C:\dev.wamp\bin\php\7.0\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 66d7cec8-aeef-424f-8553-0e3cee96c4c0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Anyone have an idea why this happened and how to fix it?

One moment I was coding, the next the power went out. When I started up my PC again, this error occured.